# Two (or multiple) t-test replaced with a single pairwise.t.test()?

Tags: t-test

This is an artificial example. I want to compare the Income of the *same* group of people (i.e. "pairing") while they were working in US, Spain, and Nigeria. In other words, I use the "US" income as a reference and simply conduct 2 Two-sample Paired T-tests:

```
t.test(dat[Country=="US",]$Income, dat[Country=="Spain",]$Income, paired=TRUE)
t.test(dat[Country=="US",]$Income, dat[Country=="Nigeria",]$Income, paired=TRUE)
```

But how is this different from the following?

```
pairwise.t.test(dat$Income, dat$Country, paired=TRUE)
```

The help for pairwise.t.test() states, "...with corrections for multiple testing". Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the only difference. This `pairwise.t.test` call should be equivalent to the direct `t.test` calls:

```
pairwise.t.test(dat$Income, dat$Country, paired=TRUE, p.adjust.method="none")
```